# Checking processor capabilities in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, cpu

I'm using FFMPEG in an app, and I'm using the following configuration:

```
--extra-cflags=' -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon'
```

I'm targeting 4.0+ so I believe armv7-a should be supported by most non Intel devices, and I'm sure the neon extension is supported in most devices as well, but I'm not sure how I can find that out for all 2000+ devices.

Is there a way to check in Android the processor type and extensions and/or in the Google Play Store to limit the apk to devices with certain processors?

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer you last question first: you can limit the apk to devices with certain processors on the Play Store, but not with the granularity you're looking for.

In short: if you upload an apk containing native libs only for armv7-a, it won't be downloadable from an x86, mips or armv6 device. But the choice stops there: both NEON and non-NEON devices are considered armv7-a devices, so that does not solve your problem. The check has to be done at runtime.

Checking the processor architecture and capabilities in Java on Android is not easy to do: there's no API for that.

On the other side, this can easily be done using the NDK, which contains a `cpufeatures` module (you can find documentation on it in your NDK install folder). This module lets you:

- find the architecture of the device using `android_getCpuFamily()`
- get *additional details* using `android_getCpuFeatures()`: this is what you're looking for, as these details contain the `ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON` flag indicating NEON compatibility!

In practice, implementing a JNI function such as the following one and calling it from Java should do the trick:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <cpu-features.h>

jboolean
Java_com_my_namespace_MyClass_isNeon
(JNIEnv *env, jclass class) {
  uint64_t features = android_getCpuFeatures();
  if ((android_getCpuFamily() != ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM)  ||
      ((features & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON) == 0  )) {
    return JNI_FALSE;
  }
  else {
    return JNI_TRUE;
  }
}
```

it will return `true` if the device is ARMv7 *and* features NEON, `false` otherwise!

Comment: If you want some more details (or background), this answer is adapted from [a blogpost](https://moodstocks.com/blog/article/ice-cream-sandwich-why-native-code-support-sucks/) I wrote some time ago. The last section is particularly relevant to what you're trying to do (the rest is mainly background).